# Putting numeric value in bottom when doing order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the thing, I am not good with sql queries. I want to put numerical values in bottom when i want to perform order by in mssql.

my query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code,value 
FROM code_value 
WHERE code = 'BR' 
ORDER BY value
```

the result i am getting is this

```
code value
BR   122333
BR   1455577
BR   193 Your Kart
BR   Junglee
BR   Kart Info
BR   Snapdeal
BR   Your Kart
```

and i want output as below

```
code value
BR   Junglee
BR   Kart Info
BR   Snapdeal
BR   Your Kart
BR   122333
BR   1455577
BR   193 Your Kart
```

Is there any workaround available to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY 
case when string_value like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end,string_value
```

EDIT

```
select  code,value from
(
SELECT DISTINCT top 100 percent code,
case when value like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end as rank,value 
FROM code_value 
WHERE code = 'BR' 
ORDER BY 
case when value like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end,value
) as t
```

Comment: *"ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified"* - he should probably wrap the `SELECT DISTINCT` in another query that does the ordering.

Comment: wrapped it, did something like this: SELECT string_value,property_code FROM 
 itm_item_properties
 WHERE organization_id = 590  
        AND property_code = 'BRAND'
  AND string_value IN (SELECT DISTINCT string_value from itm_item_properties)
        ORDER BY case when string_value like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end,string_value

Comment: @w0lf This doesn't helped. When i am firing query i am not getting unique values, i.e. i am getting multiple values. Any workaround for that

Comment: @Madhivanan Thanks it works. BTW, If you don't mind, can you explain "top 100 percent" and "as t"

Comment: When you make a derived table that hase ORDER BY clause you need to use TOP operator and as you want all rows, you need to use 100 percent. t is the alias name for the derived table

Answer (score 1):

another method that works in your specific example, use a custom function

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[RemoveNonNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^0-9]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

then, in your context:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code,value 
FROM code_value 
WHERE code = 'BR' 
order by dbo.RemoveNonNumericCharacters(value), value
```

note that outside the scope of your specific example this solution may not work as you expect.  example:  if VALUE contains a numeric digit somewhere in the string but does not start with a numeric value.  to handle this case the function would have to be modified.